# Custom <ul> image bullets not showing up in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Here is the code I am using:

```
.customBulletList {
    list-style-image: url(images/bullet.png);
}
```

The weird thing is that it shows up in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera. Is this CSS property not supported in IE or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure it's set to the ul not the li

Comment: What version of IE? 6, 7 or 8?

Answer (score 3):

it is implemented. Probably it's problem of margins, padding, that are counted wrong and put image outside visible area.

Comment: Yup: the space that the list image is displayed in is created by margins in IE, but padding in other browsers. (Or vice versa, I forget.) Sounds like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a background-image instead (with additional padding to the left) and set list-style to none.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that IE6 does not supportlist-style-image!

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But I have seen promblems with IE6 and list-style-image togehter with float!

Answer (score 0):

Add padding-left to the ul css style.  That may bring the bullets into view. Try 40px and work from there.  If you put a temporary border on the ul you can see where the bullets are getting chopped.

Comment: also check `list-style-position: inside/outside`